# How to connect through SSH to second server?

Tags: ssh

I have two servers in my home network. Local IP of main one is 192.168.1.10 the second one is 192.168.1.11. On the router I forward ports 22, 80, 443 to my main server.

How can I connect to my second server through ssh?

Comment: This is not really an Ubuntu problem. This has to do with your router settings. Some routers allow forwarding to a different port. For example you could set incoming 2222 port to forward to port 22 of 192.168.1.11. Then you won't have to change anything in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: It make sense. Thank. But what can I do with virtual hosts. On both servers I have apache2 with some virtual hosts. How can I divide and forward traffic?

Comment: I don't know anything about virtual hosts. Are these virtual machines? If so, these should have their own IP addresses. Anyways, this looks like a new and different question. If this not a different question, please edit the question above and add the new information about the virtual hosts.

Comment: You probably mean to connect from outside your network, using main server as a [jumpbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server). Try `ssh -J userMain@externalIP:22 userServer@192.168.1.11`, (`ssh -J <jumpbox> <destination>`). Advice: never use ssh default port (maybe something between 1024-32767) and disable root login.